# Python; Search and Replace; Lists; Strings

Tags: python, string, list, replace, iteration

```
    a = self.test_lockCheck():
    d = []
    for i in a.iteritems():
        d = a.replace('1','3')
```

`a` instantiates a function which `return`'s a list which contains a string for each of its indices. Each string indice will always contain a '1' which needs to be replaced by '3'. I found `replace()` in another question on this site. I was curious if anyone knew of another way? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you mean to say that `a` will be a `dict` that has `string` types for its keys, especially since you're using `a.iteritems()` which wouldn't work if `a` was a `list`.

Comment: yes there is always another way ... its hard to tell what you are trying to actually accomplish and what is wrong with the current solution? (I think you mean `d.append(a.replace('1','3'))` also its unclear what the return of test_lockCheck is ... chances are you should just modify `test_lockCheck(key)`

Comment: your example does not work... it is unclear what is being asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), instead of trying to create a new list via a `for`-loop:

```
a = [s.replace('1','3') for s in self.test_lockCheck()]
```

If you're dealing with a dictionary, you can still apply something similar:

```
a = {k.replace('1','3'): v for k,v in self.test_lockCheck().iteritems()}
```

Comment: except its not actually a list (+1 though)

Comment: @JoranBeasley *"... which `return`'s a list ..."*. Although I see what you mean, looking at the code.

Comment: however he is using iteritems ... :) ... but his example is very broken so no idea what he actually has or wants :/

Comment: I wasn't aware that `iteritems()` was used for only dicts/hashes. I assure you that what `test_lock check()` returns is a list. Sorry, for the brokenness.

Comment: @user2264406 In that case, the first snippet should work. Do let me know if it does not.

Comment: @arshajii I utilized that code and it worked. However, I am receiving an odd error that is difficult for me to explain without going into a larger back story of which you probably don't wish to hear. In short, I think I may need to create "a new list via a `for`-loop". Because, as of now with the list comprehension usage I am not achieving my desired result. If you can help me with that example I would really appreciate it! P.s. thanks for the list comprehension example, as I appreciate how concise it is!

Comment: @arshajii Here is the output from the Selenium-RC debug console of back to back commands which <i>should</i> be identical (I will post the debug output in another comment, as it is too long). However, as you can see the 'Command request' which generates an error has an extra set of '[]' as well as having double quotes. The error exception 'Command request' is being generated by `a = [s.replace('1','3') for s in self.test_lockCheck()]` making me think a `for`-loop generated list might be handled differently. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @arshajii Debug console output:  Command request: getText[//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/small, ] on session e030c133a8834038afd9d3652fe9280f
19:55:06.353 INFO - Got result: OK,Carey, Anne T. on session e030c133a8834038afd9d3652fe9280f
19:55:06.356 INFO - Command request: getText[["//form[@id='SubAvailSelectForm']/font/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/small"], ] on session e030c133a8834038afd9d3652fe9280f

Comment: @arshajii The debug console output was a bit messy when pasted in here, so I took the liberty of formatting it into an HTML doc which can be viewed [here](http://sftc.comxa.com/err_log.html)

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. My apologies for comment spamming :)  My solution is to use `[s[2:-2] for s in a]`. This strips off the first two and last two characters and it works like a charm. Thanks again for everyone's help!